# find(id) returns all rows instead of 1 - Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a model named Product and I want to use the relation in the image below
[image]

When I call `return response(Product::with('product_extra_attributes')->find(10)->get());` in my controller, I get an array with all products.

But when I call `return response(Product::with('product_extra_attributes')->where('id', '=', 10)->get());` I get the product I want.

Here is my db schema:

[image]

Any ideas why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: Don't call `get()` after `find()`.

Comment: Why you don't use this `return response(Product::with('product_extra_attributes')->where('id', '=', 10)->get());` this is correct

Comment: @Sobir It's better to use the `find` method when searching for a single record: `return response(Product::with('product_extra_attributes')->find(10));`.